# Chrome JavaScript Engine Date Parsing Defaults to Year 2001

Tags: javascript, date

In Chrome, when the string doesn't contain year, why does JavaScript default to 2001?

```
t = new Date('Monday, Jan 11')

Thu Jan 11 2001 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (Greenwich Mean Time)
```

Edit:
fwiw, this behavior is also seen in React Native

Comment: it seems to be specific to Chrome. Firefox returns an invalid date

Comment: This is a non-standard date format. As such, the result is entirely implementation dependant - the engine is allowed to use whatever parsing mode or heuristic to determine the date. I suggest either using a standard date format, which is a slimmed down version of ISO 8601, or alternatively use a date library to parse the dates.

Comment: The short answer is that parsing of timestamps in a format other than those supported by ECMA-262 is implementation dependent. You might get the expected date, some other date, or an invalid date with the same string generating different results in different implementations (or even versions of the same implementation). Hence it is strongly recommended to avoid the built–in parser.

Comment: thank you all for the answers! agreed that it is a browser specific bug. @RobG could you re-open the question? this is not an exact duplicate to the other question. i am hoping to understand the implementation in v8 regarding this particular issue. thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found this a fun question so I went digging into the source code of the **V8 engine**, the javascript engine used by [Chromium](https://www.chromium.org/) and therefore Chrome (the browser this phenomena shows up in) to reverse engineer this strange behavior.

I found this snippet in [dateparser.h](https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/master/src/date/dateparser.cc):

```
if (!is_iso_date_) {
  if (Between(year, 0, 49))
    year += 2000;
  else if (Between(year, 50, 99))
    year += 1900;
}
```

Assuming that a date without a year is not ISO compliant, `2000` or `1900` is added to the OPs undefined `year`. This should suggest there is a breakpoint above `50`, which turns out to be true:

```
// Tested in Chrome:
console.log(new Date('1 1 49').getFullYear()); // 2049
console.log(new Date('1 1 50').getFullYear()); // 1950
```

Higher up in the file `year` is defined like this:

```
int year = 0; // Default year is 0 (=> 2000) for KJS compatibility.
```

[KJS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KJS_(software)) being a very early javascript engine that was adopted by [WebKit](https://webkit.org/), which in turn was forked into Chromium, so this default value seems to be chosen for unknown compatiblity reasons with ancient ancestor engines. Following this logic though, the year should default to `2000`, not `2001`. Turns out that might have been the intention.

In the same document, this snippet occurs:

```
// Day and month defaults to 1.
while (index_ < kSize) {
  comp_[index_++] = 1;
}
```

`comp_` holds the default values for `[day, month, year]`. Judging by the comment, `kSize` should be `3` so only `day` and `month` would be set to `1` if not specified otherwise.

However, `kSize` is `4` so the loop iterates over the `year` part as well. `year` is then (if not specified) set to `1`, overwriting the `int year = 0` statement from before. The aforementioned conditional kicks in, `year += 2000` happens and you end up with the odd default value of `2001`.

I suspect this is a bug, but can't be sure as the intended behavior of parsing a nonexistent date is hard to define. You should probably be better of specifying your own default year anyway. And there ends this little speculative journey through the far away source code of the V8 engine.

Answer (score 2):

The constructor for Date if passed a string uses [Date.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse#Date_Time_String_Format) which:

Excerpt:

The ECMAScript specification states: If the String does not conform to the standard format the function may fall back to any implementation–specific heuristics or implementation–specific parsing algorithm. Unrecognizable strings or dates containing illegal element values in ISO formatted strings shall cause Date.parse() to return NaN.

However, invalid values in date strings not recognized as simplified ISO format as defined by ECMA-262 may or may not result in NaN, depending on the browser and values provided, e.g.:

```
// Non-ISO string with invalid date values
new Date('23/25/2014');
```

will be treated as a local date of 25 November, 2015 in Firefox 30 and an invalid date in Safari 7.

So the answer is a combination of, because the browser you executed it decided that, and it's not a standard so a browser may return just about anything.

Answer (score 0):

This is done by your browser, you are probably using Crome. With other browsers you can also get Invalid Date.

Comment: The OP doesn't get an invalid Date, they get an unexpected year (2001). Safari returns a Date with year 2000, Chrome a 2001 and Firefox returns an invalid Date.