# What is the logic behind the string parsing on the Date constructor in javascript for the strings "0" to "110"?

Tags: javascript, date, parsing, time, timezone-offset

I was trying to see if counting on the result of doing a `const myNewDate = new Date(dateString)` and then using an `_.isDate(myNewDate)` would be sufficient to validate that it's a "valid date", but then I thought: what can I receive in `dateString`?

It occurred to me to execute the following:
`for(i=0;i<110;i++) { console.log(i, new Date(String(i)))}`

And this is the result I got:

```
0 2000-01-01T06:00:00.000Z
1 2001-01-01T06:00:00.000Z
2 2001-02-01T06:00:00.000Z
3 2001-03-01T06:00:00.000Z
4 2001-04-01T06:00:00.000Z
5 2001-05-01T05:00:00.000Z
6 2001-06-01T05:00:00.000Z
7 2001-07-01T05:00:00.000Z
8 2001-08-01T05:00:00.000Z
9 2001-09-01T05:00:00.000Z
10 2001-10-01T05:00:00.000Z
11 2001-11-01T06:00:00.000Z
12 2001-12-01T06:00:00.000Z
13 Invalid Date
14 Invalid Date
15 Invalid Date
16 Invalid Date
17 Invalid Date
18 Invalid Date
19 Invalid Date
20 Invalid Date
21 Invalid Date
22 Invalid Date
23 Invalid Date
24 Invalid Date
25 Invalid Date
26 Invalid Date
27 Invalid Date
28 Invalid Date
29 Invalid Date
30 Invalid Date
31 Invalid Date
32 2032-01-01T06:00:00.000Z
33 2033-01-01T06:00:00.000Z
34 2034-01-01T06:00:00.000Z
35 2035-01-01T06:00:00.000Z
36 2036-01-01T06:00:00.000Z
37 2037-01-01T06:00:00.000Z
38 2038-01-01T06:00:00.000Z
39 2039-01-01T06:00:00.000Z
40 2040-01-01T06:00:00.000Z
41 2041-01-01T06:00:00.000Z
42 2042-01-01T06:00:00.000Z
43 2043-01-01T06:00:00.000Z
44 2044-01-01T06:00:00.000Z
45 2045-01-01T06:00:00.000Z
46 2046-01-01T06:00:00.000Z
47 2047-01-01T06:00:00.000Z
48 2048-01-01T06:00:00.000Z
49 2049-01-01T06:00:00.000Z
50 1950-01-01T06:00:00.000Z
51 1951-01-01T06:00:00.000Z
52 1952-01-01T06:00:00.000Z
53 1953-01-01T06:00:00.000Z
54 1954-01-01T06:00:00.000Z
55 1955-01-01T06:00:00.000Z
56 1956-01-01T06:00:00.000Z
57 1957-01-01T06:00:00.000Z
58 1958-01-01T06:00:00.000Z
59 1959-01-01T06:00:00.000Z
60 1960-01-01T06:00:00.000Z
61 1961-01-01T06:00:00.000Z
62 1962-01-01T06:00:00.000Z
63 1963-01-01T06:00:00.000Z
64 1964-01-01T06:00:00.000Z
65 1965-01-01T06:00:00.000Z
66 1966-01-01T06:00:00.000Z
67 1967-01-01T06:00:00.000Z
68 1968-01-01T06:00:00.000Z
69 1969-01-01T06:00:00.000Z
70 1970-01-01T06:00:00.000Z
71 1971-01-01T06:00:00.000Z
72 1972-01-01T06:00:00.000Z
73 1973-01-01T06:00:00.000Z
74 1974-01-01T06:00:00.000Z
75 1975-01-01T06:00:00.000Z
76 1976-01-01T06:00:00.000Z
77 1977-01-01T06:00:00.000Z
78 1978-01-01T06:00:00.000Z
79 1979-01-01T06:00:00.000Z
80 1980-01-01T06:00:00.000Z
81 1981-01-01T06:00:00.000Z
82 1982-01-01T06:00:00.000Z
83 1983-01-01T06:00:00.000Z
84 1984-01-01T06:00:00.000Z
85 1985-01-01T06:00:00.000Z
86 1986-01-01T06:00:00.000Z
87 1987-01-01T06:00:00.000Z
88 1988-01-01T06:00:00.000Z
89 1989-01-01T06:00:00.000Z
90 1990-01-01T06:00:00.000Z
91 1991-01-01T06:00:00.000Z
92 1992-01-01T06:00:00.000Z
93 1993-01-01T06:00:00.000Z
94 1994-01-01T06:00:00.000Z
95 1995-01-01T06:00:00.000Z
96 1996-01-01T06:00:00.000Z
97 1997-01-01T06:00:00.000Z
98 1998-01-01T06:00:00.000Z
99 1999-01-01T06:00:00.000Z
100 0100-01-01T05:50:36.000Z
101 0101-01-01T05:50:36.000Z
102 0102-01-01T05:50:36.000Z
103 0103-01-01T05:50:36.000Z
104 0104-01-01T05:50:36.000Z
105 0105-01-01T05:50:36.000Z
106 0106-01-01T05:50:36.000Z
107 0107-01-01T05:50:36.000Z
108 0108-01-01T05:50:36.000Z
109 0109-01-01T05:50:36.000Z
```

So, just to analyze it a little:

- from 0 to 4, the value is used for "months" at 6:00
- from 5 to 10, the value is again used for "months" but at 5:00  (why?)
- 11 and 12, the value is "months", but back to 6:00
- from 13 to 31 is an invalid date (why?)
- from 32 to 49, now the value belongs to the years: 2000 + the value (why?)
- from 50 to 99, now the value belongs to the years: 1900 + the value (why?)
- from 100 to 110 (and even more, I tried 9999 with the same result) it belongs to the year, literally: 100 becomes year 0100. But the time, is set to 5 hours, and minutes and seconds belong to my current computer minutes and seconds (why?)

This is extremely confusing. I'd love to find the source of this.

Techical notes:

- This is clearly javascript code.
- I've used node 12.16.3.
- Same result if I run it in Chrome's console.
- In Firefox, it returns all as invalid dates.

Comment: Note that `new Date(string)` uses `Date.parse(string)` behind the scenes.

Comment: Also "why does the clock turn back by an hour for 4-to-5, and then forward again for 10-to-11" has a _very_ simple answer.

Comment: @mike not every country has daylight saving time ...

Comment: "from 13 to 31 is an invalid date" well, you mentioned that it was using the value as a month. What is the thirteenth month on your calendar? As the linked duplicate's answers note, parsing anything other than certain ISO 8601 formats is implementation specific code. You'll need to look at the V8 source to know exactly what is happening for Node and Chrome. Firefox has its own implementation, as does Safari.

Comment: @JonasWilms You don't need to live in a country with DST to know it exists. If you're working with dates, timezones and "summer"/"winter" time changes are a given.

Comment: The 32 seems arbitrary though.

Comment: @JonasWilms You've not heard of the 2032 bug? It's like the Y2K bug. Everybody's going to die. Or something.

Comment: Note that the time defaults are offsets (of the local time) not the actual time of the Date.

`date = new Date("0) // → 2000-01-01T06:00:00.000Z`
`date.getHours()   // → 0`
`(2000-01-01T00:00:00-06:00)`

Comment: @HereticMonkey if I replace `new Date` with `Date.parse` I get the timestamps (and makes sense). For 13 to 31, it returns NaN. If then I wrap it with `new Date(Date.parse...)` I get the same result as the OP.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans curious about the simple answer :) To me it lands on the whoever did it @ google was having fun playing with this.

Comment: Some notes I found around it, but very vague: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse#compatibility_notes

Comment: Thus proving my point. I didn't say that `new Date(string)` returns the same thing as `Date.parse(string)`; I said that `new Date(string)` *uses* `Date.parse(string)` behind the scenes. You can see it in the spec: https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-date At step 4.c.ii.2., "Let tv be the result of parsing v as a date, in exactly the same manner as for the parse method (21.4.3.2)." So it runs `Date.parse("13")` and gets `NaN`, which, converted to a `Date`, is `Invalid Date`.

Comment: @JonasWilms How'd you get that? Best I could find was https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/lkgr/src/date/dateparser-inl.h which is great, if you know C or whatever, but a little harder to parse if you don't know the language.

Comment: @heretic right, you've just found the native binding that is called by the DateConstructor (which is probably the root of all evil). It's C++, though the actual tricky thing is trying to understand the parser (it's spread across all files in the /date folder)

Comment: Parsing of unsupported string formats is implementation dependent. This exercise is pointless.

Comment: @RobG It is not pointless from the point of view that one has to build code that does proper validations across all different runtimes, and each one of them handling a use case on their own way will mess with userland code. At least this is useful to understand expected results in V8 based uses vs others

Comment: @LuisLoboBorobia Not sure what your goal is here. Do you want to write your own [date validator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1766513/1048572)? If so, define the acceptable input format and parse it yourself. Try not to utilise the `Date` constructor (or `Date.parse`) for this.

Comment: @JonasWilms While not every country uses DST (oh! the blessed!), the OP uses a computer that is set to a timezone that has a DST… so he's probably familiar with the phenomenon.

Comment: @LuisLoboBorobia—the solution is do not use the built–in parser except for the two supported formats in recent implementations (and even then, manual parsing is preferred for risk–averse scenarios). Otherwise you're going to have to document the behaviour of not only every implementation, but every version of every implementation for every format you wish to support and hope that you can accurately determine the version from the user agent string, which is notoriously fraught.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> from 0 to 4, the value is used for "months" at 6:00

The default offset will be your locale which is -6 during these months.
According to author Ryan Dahl, "Default year is 0 (=> 2000) for [KJS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KJS_(software)) compatibility".
You might have noticed that the year changes from 2000 to 2001… I believe this is a bug. See: [existing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65658435/1656960)

> from 5 to 10, the value is again used for "months" but at 5:00 (why?)

> 11 and 12, the value is "months", but back to 6:00

DST changes in your locale, which is the default offset

> from 13 to 31 is an invalid date (why?)

Because the string supplied is not a valid month or YYYY it is parsed as DD and a Date with only a day value doesn't make sense. Why it does not default MM or YY is unclear… Speculating, the reason might be ambiguity between YY and DD, when parsing.

> from 32 to 49, now the value belongs to the years: 2000 + the value
> (why?)

> from 50 to 99, now the value belongs to the years: 1900 + the value
> (why?)

PHP's `strptime`, Python's `datetime.strptime` and UNIX C's `strptime`  assume that 00-68 years belong to 2000 and 69-99 belong to 1900.
This is intended to be an API convenience, assuming that lower numbers 32:49, closer the current century, are of the current century and that higher numbers 50:99, closer to the previous century, are referring to said century.

> from 100 to 110 (and even more, I tried 9999 with the same result) it
> belongs to the year, literally: 100 becomes year 0100

`YYY` (when > 99) is literally `YYY` AD, akin to ISO-years

> But the time, is set to 5 hours, and minutes and seconds belong to my
> current computer minutes and seconds (why?)

Timezones do change over time, and the locale parsing will try to account for those.

```
> (new Date("1883-05-31")).getTimezoneOffset()
350
> (new Date("1893-05-31")).getTimezoneOffset()
360
> (new Date("2023-05-31")).getTimezoneOffset()
300
```

However, dates prior to Unix epoch never include [the timezone's name](http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat/DateTimeFormat), and Dates using a North American locale, prior to November 18, 1883 do not use the modern GMT offset as [it was not yet established](https://www.loc.gov/item/today-in-history/november-18/#:%7E:text=On%20November%2018%2C%201883%2C%20precisely,Standard%20Railway%20Time(SRT).).

```
> new Date("1883", "10", "18", "12").toString()
'Sun Nov 18 1883 12:00:00 GMT-0550 (Central Standard Time)'
> new Date("1883", "10", "18", "13").toString()
'Sun Nov 18 1883 13:00:00 GMT-0600 (Central Standard Time)'
```

(The change occurred early noon)

```
> new Date("1883", "10", "18", "12", "09").toString()
'Sun Nov 18 1883 12:09:00 GMT-0550 (Central Standard Time)'
> new Date("1883", "10", "18", "12", "09", "24").toString()
'Sun Nov 18 1883 12:09:24 GMT-0600 (Central Standard Time)'
```

Comment: All of this is guesswork based on observed behaviour, some of it is easily proved wrong, e.g. "*dates prior to \[1970-01-01\] never include the timezone's name*" is refuted by `new Date(1900,0).toString()` returning a string that includes my timezone name. "*dates prior to November 19, 1984, do not use the modern GMT offset*" yet it's included in `new Date(1900,0).toLocaleString('en-ca', {timeZoneName:'short'})`. According to your link, the use of GMT across Britain was officially standardised in 1890. I have no idea why 19 Nov 1984 is relevant. The use of UTC started in 1960.

Comment: The date is 1883 and there was a mismatch in the answer between the snippet and the text which I've corrected.

Comment: @RobG If not using `Intl`, the current locale/TZ info is used. But there is a point to be made that that exclusion is not an inherent behavior of `Date` or `Date.parse`