# Why is "best-of-5" a valid JavaScript date?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Why does `new Date("best-of-5")` parse as `2001-04-30T22:00:00.000Z` in Chrome and Node?

Comment: [_"...the value produced by this function is implementation-defined when given any String value that does not conform to the Date Time String Format"_](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/numbers-and-dates.html#sec-date-constructor) Why are you parsing `"best-of-5"` as if it was a date?

Comment: The `5` is being treated as the month number, so it's May 1. You're getting April 30 because of the time zone conversion.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I have a code that tries to `Date.parse` unknown strings trying to figure out what's their type 

Comment: @Barmar but why it's 2001?

Comment: I think everything else is being defaulted from a baseline date.

Comment: `new Date("04-20")` returns April 20, 2001.

Comment: Note a [mre] would be `new Date("5")`, the rest is being ignored. This is why everything you read strongly recommends not passing anything but a [Date Time String Format](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/numbers-and-dates.html#sec-date-time-string-format) (i.e. ISO8601, `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ`) without being explicit about how it should be parsed!

Comment: @TomaszCichociński that's a losing proposition in Javascript, which applies type conversion liberally and constantly. You almost certainly want to look at the system that's accepting those strings, and put some kind of type _validation_ in front of that, rather than running type _inference_ much, much later. Or at the very least use type checkers that don't coerce/convert types (so don't use `Date`, but a real date validator that knows what format real dates can have and rejects things that don't match that)

Comment: [_"Enough making fun of languages that suck, let's talk about JavaScript."_](https://www.destroyallsoftware.com/talks/wat)

Comment: check soimon's answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65657805/chrome-javascript-engine-date-parsing-defaults-to-year-2001